# Count number of rectangles

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There is **NxM** grid present with numbering as `1,2,...NM`(numbering is done row wise. 1st row will contain number from **1** to **M**, second row will contain **M+1** to **2M** and so on).

There is also list given of **X** numbers which ranges from **1** to **NM**.

**Problem**: *Count total number of rectangles with sides on the grid lines and it contains exactly **K** points from the list **X** for each **K** ranging from **0** to **length of X**.

Example is worth more than 1000 words:

```
Let N=2, M=2 and X=[1,2].
Rectangle containing 0 points: 3
Rectangle containing 1 points: 4
Rectangle containing 2 points: 2
```

**My approach**

I know total number of rectangles possible from this grid is`n(n+1)m(m+1)/4` but could not think of anything else.

**EDIT**
1 ≤ N, M ≤ 10^7
1 ≤ length of X ≤ 10^5
1 ≤ Elements in list X ≤ N*M

Comment: @Rishav I believe that each number in X encodes a cell from the grid.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.. @Mike can you please expand upon it?

Comment: Consider 3x6 grid looks like http://i.imgur.com/wvzXBk0.png <br> List X contains 4,10,2. I need to count number of rectangles using the sides of grid such that there is one of 4,10 and 2 inside them. Similarly for K=2, Number of rectangles containing 4,10 or 4,2 or 10,2 inside them and so on.

Comment: I need to count the number of rectangles containg 0 points from list X, containing 1 point from list X, containing 2 point from X, finally containing 3 points from list X

Comment: Is this from an active contest? https://www.codechef.com/FEB16/problems/RECTLOVE

Comment: [Also posted on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1644108/14578).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Copied from a live CodeChef programming contest: https://www.codechef.com/FEB16/problems/RECTLOVE.  Please don't do that.  Many consider it cheating, as the CodeChef rules prohibit seeking outside help.  Also, copying material without attribution constitutes plagiarism / [a violation of our rules regarding referencing](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), and that is not considered acceptable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is a `O(n^2 * m^2)` approach.

Number the row grid lines as `row[0], ..., row[n]` and the column grid lines as `column[0], ..., column[n]`. Let `f[x][y]` denote the number of points in `X` contained in the rectangle with  top side - `row[0]`, bottom side - `row[x]`, left side - `column[0]`, right side - `column[y]`. Note that you can calculate `f` in a bottom-up approach only for `O(n*m)` time (it's dynamic programming).

Now for each rectangle with with  top side - `row[x1]`, bottom side - `row[x2]`, left side - `column[y1]`, left side `column[y2]` (`x1<x2`, `y1<y2`) you can calculate the total number of `X` points in it to be `f[x2][y2]-f[x1][y2]-f[x2][y1]+f[x1][y1]`. After you calculate the number you put in a counting map which associates the number of points in `X`  contained in the current rectangle with how many times you've encountered this number. You can use `hashmap`.

In total you have `O(n^2*m^2)`.

In your example, for `f` you have:

```
f[0][0] = f[0][1] = f[0][2] = f[1][0] = f[2][0] = 0
f[1][1] = 1
f[1][2] = 2
f[2][1] = 1
f[2][2] = 2
```

Now, for the rectangle `row[0], row[1], column[1], column[2]` you have the number of points in `X` which are contained in this rectangle to be:

```
number = f[1][2]-f[0][2]-f[1][1]+f[0][0] = 2-0-1+0 = 1
```

which is correct.

Note that the bruteforce approach has complexity `O(n^4 * m^4)`.

Comment: I have edited the question with constraints. It would be better if you can reduce the algorithm to O(length of X) or something like that.