# At most k 1's submatrix in the matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I am solving a problem where we are given a square binary grid. We have to find the number of rectangles where the number of 1's is at most k in following time complexity: **O(N^2 log(N)k)**.

I am not able to think of any approach to this time complexity. Is it even possible and if yes how can we approach it?

Comment: What is N? The number of rows? The number of cells?

Comment: @trincot N is the number of rows and columns.

Comment: What time complexity are you able to achieve? Explaining your attempt, even if it is brute force/doesn't meet your desired time bound, can usually lead you to better solutions. How would you approach a simpler subproblem-- counting the rectangles with no 1's?

Comment: There's been a few similar questions, e.g. [this post about the 'exactly k' problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321927/how-to-check-sums-of-all-possible-rectangles-of-array) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254838/count-number-of-rectangles) about finding answers for each value from 0 to k. Since this is definitely solvable in `O(n^3)` time, you only have to solve the case where `k < n/log(n)`